# Adhoc styling in Material-UI 5

Tags: material-ui

Trying to upgrade from MUI 4 to 5. In MUI 4, I used to be able to introduce adhoc classes using `makeStyles`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
    root: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
    },
}));

export const FakeLink = ({ children }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <span className={classes.root}>
            {children}
        </span>
    );
};
```

Now trying to put the same `cursor: 'pointer'` on an `ImageListItem`. How do I do this?

```
<ImageListItem>
    <img ... />
</ImageListItem>
```

I thought I could do it using `sx`, but it doesn't implement the `cursor` property. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor property should be supposed by the sx and styled API. Maybe you are facing a TypeScript issue?

Comment: Thanks, Olivier. I had missed this sentence in the docs: "This prop provides a superset of CSS".